# Whats wrong with if (($x > 0 && 256 <= $x) || ($y > 0 && 256 <= $y))?

Tags: php, conditional-statements

Whats wrong with

```
if (($x > 0 && 256 <= $x) || ($y > 0 && 256 <= $y)) { 
//Do AWESOME action here 
} else { 
echo '<br><div align="center"><b>X and Y must be over 0 but equal or less than 256.</b></div>'; 
}
```

? That means if X is over 0 and X is 256 or less and y is over 0 and less then or equal to 256, to do somthing, right? I put in x 237 and y 144, it gives me a error saying "X and Y must be over 0 but equal or less than 256."

Comment: Also, you would probably want to check $x is **less than** 256 because those are the limits of a typical unsigned byte.

Comment: Both x and y to be from 1 to 256 right ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   if (($x > 0 && 256 >= $x) || ($y > 0 && 256 >= $y))
```

But rather start with $x

```
   if (($x > 0 && $x <= 256) || ($y > 0 && $y <= 256))
```

Just like you would say in speech: **x is less than or equal to 256**.

Comment: Thanks. I like how you give a example on how it would be in a speech. Helpful to remember when doing theses things.

Comment: Alternatively I also like writing  `(0 < $x && $x <= 256)` which shows that `$x` is between 0 and 256 by literally having the variable between them visually.

Comment: I guess both are OK while you pick one closer to your heart and stick with it for the rest of your life :)

Answer (score 6):

It should be

```
if (($x > 0 && $x <= 256) || ($y > 0 && $y <= 256)) {
    // Rest of your code
}
```

Before you where checking for it to be higher than 0 and higher or equal than 256, not lower or equal than 256.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant

```
if (($x > 0 &&  $x <= 256 ) || ($y > 0 && $y <= 256)){...}
```

Answer (score 1):

here, try this:

```
(($x > 0 && 256 >= $x) || ($y > 0 && 256 >= $y))
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewritten those are:

```
if ($x > 0 && $x >= 256) {
// ...
}
```

Which is probably not what you meant. Use this:

```
if ($x > 0 && $x <= 256) {
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want x and y both greater the 0 and less the equal to 256.

```
if($x > 0 && $x <= 256 && $y > 0 && $y<= 256) {
```